# The usage of "of"

Tags: grammar

1. My book = book of mine
2. Mathematics games = games of mathematics

## Questions

1. How to represent "A new type of food" without "of" as shown on the left side in the given examples above?
2. Is  "food of a new type" also grammatically correct?

Comment: "A new food type" comes naturally ("type" is the subject, "food" the modifier). With "food of a new type", you are talking about the food (subject), not the type (modifier). It is correct, just different in meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MorganFR says, you could say "a new food type".

Yes, "food of a new type" is valid and would mean essentially the same thing. Arguably it shifts the emphasis from "type" to "food".

If you're asking this for practical reasons, I think "a new type of food" is the natural way to say it. I don't know why you'd want to avoid the "of". But maybe you're wondering about the principle and not the best phrasing for a real document.

"Type" is a rather vague word. Depending on what you're actually talking about, you might want to look for something more specific. (As a programmer, I constantly struggle with every classification being called a "type": "customer type", "product type", "order type", etc. And what if there are two ways that we classify the same thing? Like a customer could be "individual" or "business", and a customer could also be "domestic" or "foreign". We can't call them both "customer type". Etc.)